# Problema con actualizacion de RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-volley

Tengo un RecyclerView en Android que descarga datos con un PHP y con Volley, y luego muestra una lista de imagenes con texto. Cuando llamo a otra Activity que sirve para filtrar busquedas de esos objetos en la BBDD, presiono el boton aplicar flitro, y vuelve a la Main Activity de nuevo donde estaba el RecyclerView. Se supone que este deberia actualizarse y mostrar solo los registros nuevos con los filtros aplicados, sin embargo, muestra como primer objeto el que encuentra con el filtro aplicado, y luego sigue mostrando los demas objetos que mostraba inicialmente la aplicacion. No se si es un problema de actualizacion del RecyclerView o no. Este es el codigo del metodo que rellena la lista con los objetos filtrados.

```
public static boolean filter=false;
private List<PlumImage> listPlums;

    //Creating Views
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context=this;

    //Initializing Views
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    listPlums = new ArrayList<>();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(filter), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (filter==false){ //If filter is not enabled
        getData();
    }
    else{
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(FiltersActivity.CATEGORY), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getDataFilter();
    }

    recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);

    adapter = new PlumAdapter(listPlums, this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }

private void getDataFilter() {
    //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer
    requestQueue.add(getDataFromServerFilter(requestCount));
    //Incrementing the request counter
    requestCount++;
}

private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServerFilter(int requestCount) {
    //Initializing ProgressBar
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    //Displaying Progressbar
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    //JsonArrayRequest of volley
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(AppConfig.FILTER_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount)+"&category="+FiltersActivity.CATEGORY,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                    parseDataFilter(response);
                    //Hiding the progressbar
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    //Returning the request
    return jsonArrayRequest;
}

private void parseDataFilter(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        //Creating the plum object
        PlumImage plum = new PlumImage();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            //Getting json
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding data to the plum object
            plum.setPhoto(json.getString(AppConfig.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
            plum.setName(json.getString(AppConfig.TAG_NAME));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Adding the plum object to the list
        listPlums.add(plum);
    }

    //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
    recyclerView.destroyDrawingCache();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya esta solucionado. El problema residía en el orden de llamada a la creación de la lista filtrada.

Comment: Hola @Lopiv2. Gracias por avisar que lo solucionaste. Sin embargo, si alguien más tuviese el mismo problema, ¿no crees que le serviría ver el detalle de cómo lo solucionaste? Quizás tu respuesta se podría beneficiar enormemente si pusieras el código solucionado. Luego, podrás aceptar esta respuesta haciendo click en el ✔️ a la izquierda (o aceptar otra respuesta que hayas recibido si fue eso lo que solucionó tu problema)

Answer (score 1):

Veo que tienes estas lineas, que son llamadas cuando se ejecuta `onResponse()`:

```
   //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
    recyclerView.destroyDrawingCache();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

pero debes recordar que es importante llamar nuevamente `setAdapter()` para actualizar el `RecyclerView`, posteriormente llamar `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

```
adapter = new PlumAdapter(listPlums, this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Con esto lograras la actualización de tus datos.

Comment: He añadido este codigo, pero sigue sin funcionar. Lo que hace es que a los datos añadidos anteriormente, cuando aplico el filtro, efectivamente aparece un registro que solo sobreeescribe el primer elemento anterior, y sigue mostrando el resto.

Comment: El adapter PlumAdapter() debe tener la lista de nuevos elementos, revisa  que listPlums en realidad tenga los nuevos, no los nuevos y los anteriores.

Comment: Vale, lo he solucionado utilizando una nueva lista para los filtros, ahora la ultima pregunta, ¿Por que solo me muestra un registro en el RecyclerView a la hora de filtrar, y cuando tiene que mostrar todos sin filtros muestra todos? Estoy utilizando un sistema Feed, que solo carga x elementos por pagina. Si en el PHP aumento el numero de elementos por pagina veo hasta ese numero de elementos, pero el resto no.

Comment: Primero asegura que el listado de elementos dentro de listPlums, este de acuerdo a tus requerimientos, puedes revisar realizando debuggin antes de enviar al adapter si en verdad trae el listado cuando aplicas filtros o no.

Comment: Ya lo he mirado pero por algún motivo solo recibe un elemento por página, que lo controla la variable Requestcount. Cuando está variable no se manda a getdatafromserverfilter funciona correctamente. Sin embargo esto funciona correctamente en getdatafromserver y hace el feed correctamente.

Comment: Ivan el metodo getCount() debe retornar el numero de elementos, regularmente se define como private int getCount() { return listelementos.size(); }